# How to create a contextmenu/pop-up menu in a web application using Visual studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

i'm developing a web application and would like to create a pop-up menu when i right click on my webform. 
so i tried to search a toolbar item to insert on the webform, but nothing related to context menu like 'Menu strip' or 'context menu' options are available in my visual studio toolbar.

Can anyone kindly suggest me how to create a right click pop up menu to my web form using visual studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create your own using javascript/jQuery. You would need to get the pointer at the time of right click and display a div there with absolute/fixed positioning. Alternatively, there are quite a lot of jQuery plugins available that provide such functionality. A quick google search of 'jQuery right click menu' will more than likely bring up many results!